# How I can combine the text properties in a variable for using globally?

Tags: text, combinations, phaser-framework

How I can combine the text properties in a variable for using globally?

Thanks you in advance for helping !

```
var text = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + 50, 'Challenge your friends!');
    text.font = 'Arial'; // here it is the property of phaser
    text.fontSize = '12px';  // here it is the property of phaser
    text.align = 'center'; // here it is the property of phaser
    text.fontWeight = 'bold'; // here it is the property of phaser
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you just need to take advantage of the style object that the text constructor takes.  See http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Text.html#Text

You can create a global variable somewhere, for example:

```
GLOBAL_TEXTSTYLE = {font : '12px Arial', font-weight: 'bold', align: 'center' };
```

And then use it in function calls:

```
var text = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + 50,
                         'Challenge your friends!', GLOBAL_TEXTSTYLE);
```

Some people store things like this within a property of the game object.  You risk having name collisions with game's other properties, but you could do this via:

```
 // Create an object to store my game variables
 game.myGlobals = {};
 game.myGlobals.textStyle = {font:'12px Arial', font-weight:'bold', align:'center' };
```

Then use it:

```
 var text = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY + 50, 
                          'Challenge your friends!', game.myGlobals.textStyle);
```